# get pagination range number in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.1

I'm working with laravel 5.1
I want to get the range of every page shown in a blade view
for example if i have 30 records

```
 $employees= \Auth::user()->employees()->paginate(10);
```

for every page 10

I want to write the number in the blade view like this

for the first page

from **1** to **10** from total **30**

for the second page

from **11** to **20** from total **30**

for the third page

from **21** to **30** from total **30**

for the total it's easy by calling total() method

but what about others ? is there any solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the paginate methods as follows:

```
 $employees= \Auth::user()->employees()->paginate(10);
 $employees->currentPage() // Current page number
 $employees->total() // Total items
 $employees->perPage() // Per page
```

Now you can use the formula:

```
{{$employees->currentPage()}} of 
{{ $employees->total() / $employees->perPage() }}
// eg: 1 of 3
```

and

```
{{($employees->currentPage()-1)* $employees->perPage() + 1}} to 
{{ ($employees->currentPage()-1)* $employees->perPage() + $employees->perPage() }} from   
{{ $employees->total() }}
 // eg: 11 to 20 from 30
```

Comment: i think there is an error in the logic of calculation , it shows me more than the records I have and doesn't start from 1

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check again.

Comment: Now it seems good but there is a little problem starting from the  second page it adds one more record that I don't have in the **to**

Comment: Okay, let me check it. Actually I edited the question two times. Did you check the latest one?

Comment: I checked again it adds one more item only in the last page

Comment: Okay, how are you getting the output in the second page?

Comment: thank you so much I solved the problem now everything works 
good , for the last page i added an if statement , if it's  greater than the total I put the total itself and that's it

Answer (score 3):

You can use below
Showing {{ $shops->firstItem() }} to {{ $shops->lastItem() }}
of total {{$shops->total()}} entries